# How to generate an arbitrary object property that's not in use?

Tags: javascript, function, hash, hashmap

I have a bound function `f`:

`var f = someFunction.bind(this);`

Rather than passing `f` to a function, I save it in an object and instead pass an id to `f`:

```
var obj = {};
var nextID = Object.keys(obj).length;
obj[nextID] = f;
// pass nextID to some other function
```

However, I also want to delete entries at some point:

`delete obj[someID]`

This is a problem, because if I add some bound functions `a` and `b` and then delete `a`, the next id I get will be 1, and the bound function I put there will overwrite `b`.

What I could do is:

```
function getNextID() {
    var possibleID = Object.keys(obj).length;
    while (obj[possibleID])
        possibleID *= 2; // or some other mutation

    return possibleID;
}
```

But this feels ugly.

I tried using the bound functions as the key, but that didn't work:

```
obj[a] = a;
obj[b] = b;
console.log(Object.keys(obj).length); // 1
```

How can I get an arbitrary object property that isn't currently in use? Surely I'm overthinking this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I should just use arrays.

```
var arr = [];

function f() { }
function f2() { }

var a = f.bind(this);
var b = f2.bind(this);

arr.push(a);
var id = arr.length; // 1

delete arr.id;

arr.push(b);
console.log(arr.length); // 2
```